# Adding id's to a DIV. Jquery

Tags: jquery, onload

I want to add a series of ID's to a div with same classes.

Sample:

```
<div class="sample" id="id_1"></div>
<div class="sample" id="id_2"></div>
<div class="sample" id="id_3"></div>
<div class="sample" id="id_4"></div>
```

Here is the link of my project [enter link description here](http://cheapnextdaywristbands.co.uk/product/custom-design/)

[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76i0z.jpg)

I am using this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fpd-item').each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('id', 'id_'+(i+1));
});
```

Which is apparently working if I trigger using `.on(click)`
like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#primary').on( "click", '.gchoice_3_10_1', function(i){
    $('.fpd-item').each(function(i){
      $(this).attr('id', 'id_'+(i+1));
    });        
  });
});
```

But the problem is, I want the ID's to be added after the the page has loaded, not on clicking events.

Comment: So don't define it to be in a click event? You're already using $(document).ready, so why would you create a .click event if you do not wish it to be in one. In order to achieve the desired result, put the contents of the onclick event callback in the document.ready event.

Comment: There is nothing with class `fpd-item`.

Comment: that's the problem its not working if I don't define it on click! I want to add the id's after the page load. I am suspecting it has something to do with ajax, but I dont know how to solve it.

Comment: Well you are missing a set of braces in first code block...is that the exact code? Any errors in console?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally found the solution:

```
    $(window).bind("load", function() {
        $('.fpd-item').each(function(i){
          $(this).attr('id', 'id_'+(i+1));
        });        
    });
```

by replaying $( document ).ready(function() { whith $(window).bind("load", function() {

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
        // content here        
 });
```

Comment: this makes no sense`.load()` and `bind('load'` are same thing so no need to nest them

Comment: my solution as suggested works pretty well. https://jsfiddle.net/freedev/h5b1ubhr/2/

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way to do it is use `attr(prop,function)`. This won't solve why your code isn't working other than you have a missing set of braces in code shown but it does look cleaner

```
$(function(){

    $('.fpd-item').attr('id',function(i){
          return 'id_'+(i+1);
    });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the following suggestions:

1. In your example there is a missing closing bracket and parenthesis.
2. I also suppose you must be sure that `fpd-item` exists at load time.

So this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fpd-item').each(function(i){
      $(this).attr('id', 'id_'+(i+1));
      // Added just to ssho
      $(this).text('id_'+(i+1));
    });        
});
```

I have tried this here and it works:

https://jsfiddle.net/freedev/h5b1ubhr/2/

Comment: In the example there is a missing closing brackets